# Reheating Frozen Brocolli Fritters

Tags: reheating, frozen

Bought some frozen brocolli fritters from a restaurant. But as it was closing time and the cooks had left, I couldn't get any proper instructions on how to reheat them.

I have a very basic baking oven with a dial for temperature and timer. Have the following doubts:

- Should I thaw the fritters first before putting them in the oven? (If yes, for how long?) Or can I straight away put them into the oven and start reheating them?
- Should the oven be pre-heated?
- At what temperature should I reheat them?
- For how long should I bake them?

Comment: Fritters would ordinarily be fried, not oven-baked (hence the name).

Comment: I was specifically told not to fry them but bake them. I presume they may be already fried and frozen?

Comment: Yes, that sounds likely. Are the fritters browned on at least one side?

Comment: Yes, they are evenly browned.

Comment: I thought you were told you didn't get any instructions @sfxedit, but now you say you were told not to fry them. What instructions were you given and by whom?

Comment: @GdD That's the only instruction I received by the cashier who sold it to me - he specifically said they are to be baked and not fried, but couldn't tell me at what temperature and for how long, as everybody in the kitchen had left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you say that you were told to bake the fritters rather than frying them. That implies that they're already cooked, and just need to be reheated.

A fan-assisted oven would be ideal for this, but a regular oven will work too. Put the fritters, still frozen, on a baking sheet or metal baking pan in the middle of the oven. Assuming the fritters are around 1/2 inch thick, 15 minutes at 200C (400F) in a regular oven or at 180C (350F) in a fan-assisted oven should suffice. (As with any cooking instructions, preheat the oven to the specified temperature unless you're told otherwise.) Flip them halfway through cooking. By the time they're done, you'll likely see a small amount of bubbling at the surface, even in the center.

An easy way to check whether a food has come up to temperature is to stab it straight through the middle with a metal fork. Let the fork sit in there for a few seconds, then put the part of the fork tines which were in the middle of the food just in front of your closed lips. If you can't feel heat radiating off them, then gently touch them to your lips. That should give you an idea of how much the food has warmed.

Comment: I experimented and found that I had to heat them at 250C for 15 minutes (preheating the oven for 10 minutes before).  The tip with the fork was very useful. Thanks.